# Using an inverse relationship twice?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, foreign-keys, relationship

I would like to know if I can use the same inverse relationship twice for 2 different relationships?

Here is an example :

Trip

- Origin (to-one relationship) MapPoint       (inverse ReferencedBy)
- Destination (to-one relationship) MapPoint  (inverse ReferencedBy)

MapPoint

- ReferencedBy (to-many relationship) Trip (here is the problem, how to set the inverse ?)

Answer (score 0):

No you can't or shouldn't. I tried and it causes mayhem.

So that MapPoint should have 2 relationship.

ReferencedByOrigin
ReferencedByDestination

It may look strange at first. But think about it. There is nothing wrong with this approach.

Another approach is to have a one to many relationship from MapPoint to Origin and Destination and put an enum.

This approach is more elegant but actually far more complicated.

Another approach is to have 2 subEntities of Origin and Destination.

This one is more elegant but still you will need

```
ReferencedByOrigin
ReferencedByDestination
```

in the MapPoint.

Comment: It raises the warning: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38258510/the-inverse-relationship-for-does-not-reciprocate-an-inverse-relationship How can I fix it?