# The inverse relationship for <...> does not reciprocate an inverse relationship

Tags: core-data, xcdatamodel

I have the table A with the following relationships:

```
Relationship Destination Inverse
input        B           state
output       B           state
```

And the table B with the following relationship:

```
Relationship Destination Inverse
state        A           input
```

And I get the warning:

> The inverse relationship for state.input does not reciprocate an inverse relationship

Is there a right way how can I fix the warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have the same relationship name `state` for different relationships on the other side.

Either rename the state relationships to `inputState` and `outputState`.

Or add an additional entity that manages this relationship and keeps track of the relationship type with an input/output attribute.

Although I would not recommend the last solution (too complicated), you might need it if the `state` relationship of `B` should be input/output agnostic.

```
A (inOut) <----->> (as) State (b) <<--------> (state) B
```